# Как удалить вводимое число из каждой строки файла

Tags: python

есть такой файл(представлен ниже)
Как в нём можно  реализовать удаление любого, например, числа, которое пользователь вводит с клавиатуры.
Например, пользователь вводит "135" и число 135 должно удалиться из каждой строки файла.

```
Магазин;50000000; 120, 132, 135;01101
Усадьба;50000000;131, 313, 135;01102
ТЦ;8000000;896, 159, 152;01103
ЖК;7000000;569, 135, 313;01104
```

Comment: А в чем конкретная проблема с удалением-то? Читайте весь файл, да удаляйте все подобные элементы. хоть тем же `replace`.

Comment: в replace можно вносить конкретное значение, а здесь нужно удалять значение, которое с каждой итерацией может быть разным, т.к. вводится с клавиатуры

Comment: Кто вам такое сказал?)

Comment: colden, есть в Python такое понятие, как переменная. Она, конечно, в нём не совсем переменная, но это не важно, для `replace` она вполне себе ничего:-) Написанный код не забудьте, пожалуйста, выложить в качестве ответа.

Comment: А вот это значение с клавиатуры у вас попадает куда?

Comment: Значение с клавиатуры вводится, а дальше во всём файле оно должно удалиться полностью.
Конкретного кода нет, ибо не знаю как реализовать это

Comment: Тогда вам стоит начать с самого начала учебника.